# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'az.card.isOfflinePaymentsEnabled')

Tags: react-native, npm, node-modules, metro-bundler

So the alert was thrown by Sentry, and it looks like this

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'az.card.isOfflinePaymentsEnabled') at <global> (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:11:1) at <global> (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:11:1) at <global> (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:11:1) at <global> (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:11:1) at <global> (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:11:1) ... (16 additional frame(s) were not displayed)`

I reviewed this file and did not discover any matches with this. Does anyone know what this means and how to resolve the issue?

Node version: 16.14.2
Npm version: 8.5.0
Environment: Mac M1. Tested on iPhone 13 Pro simulator, IOS - 15.5